# How to use event delegation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-events, delegation

I have 2 `<span>`s loaded from 2 different ajax scripts upon selection from a dropdown box; so my code is something like this:

```
<span id='room_rate'>1, 000</span> // loaded by an ajax script
<span id='total_misc'>500</span> // loaded by another ajax script

<input type='text' id='total'/>

<button type='button' id='compute_total'>Compute</button>
```

Question:

**How to use event delegation to get the values from the 2 `<span>` and display it in the `input text total` after clicking the `compute button` ?**

---

#### What I've tried:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(this).on('click', 'span', function () {
        var room_rate = $('#room_rate').val();
        var total_misc = $('#total_misc').val();

        alert(room_rate + total_misc);
    });
});
```

#### What I get:

I don't get the alert and also I don't get an error in the console (<kbd>F12</kbd>).

Comment: There's no need to wrap a `document` event handler in a *ready* handler

Comment: http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read the *fine* manual...

[`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

> The `.val()` method is primarily used to get the values of form elements such as `input`, `select` and `textarea`.

You probably want [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

I'd also add the delegation to your button, not the spans, ie

```
$(document).on('click', '#compute_total', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $('#total').val($('#room_rate').text() + $('#total_misc').text());
});
```

Comment: still the alert has to come with undefined or empty value right

Comment: @ArunPJohny My guess was they were clicking the *button* but the delegation handler was listening for *span* clicks

Comment: I assume addition is wanted instead of string concatenation. If so, you'll need to convert the strings to numbers.

Comment: tried your code sir but I still can't get the alert

Comment: @cookiemonster Might be hard considering the number format in the example.

Comment: @Þaw might be because my answer has no `alert` :)

Comment: No sir I've put an alert, just had a typo error with the id. I get it now sir, thank you very much!

Comment: `.text().replace(/[^\d\.]/g, "")`

Comment: So sir in the `on()` the first param is the event then the second should be the id of the element that triggers the event?

Comment: I get the alert but am not able to display it in the text field maybe its because of the datatype

Comment: @Þaw Not just the ID but any valid selector. I really suggest you start reading the manual for the methods you intend on using